# Triggering "CanExecute" on postsharp [Command] when a document changes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, postsharp

I am currently migrating a project to PostSharp to remove a lot of boilerplate code, most of it is going very smoothly but I'm left confused about how to force a command to recheck if it `CanExecute`. I expected PostSharp would inspect the command like it does properties to check for dependencies, here is a minimalist sample

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MyWindowViewModel
{
    /// Anything bound to this refreshes just fine as expected
    public ObservableCollection<SomeType> Documents = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>();

   [Command]
   public ICommand AddDocumentCommand { get; set; }
   public void ExecuteAddDocument () { Documents.Add(new SomeType()); }

   [Command]
   public ICommand CloseDocumentCommand { get; set; }
   public bool CanExecuteCloseDocument () => Documents.Any(); 
   public void ExecuteCloseDocument () { Documents.Remove(Documents.Last()); }        
}
```

At start the collection is empty and the button attached to the close command is greyed as expected, however adding a document through the button attached to `AddDocument` doesn't activate the close document button, what is the appropriate way to accomplish what I need? Is PostSharp only considering assignments and not method calls as changes or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to their [Command](http://doc.postsharp.net/command) documentation

`CanExecuteCloseDocument` should be a property

```
public bool CanExecuteCloseDocument => Documents.Any();
```

The method option is used when the command requires parameters,

> The command availability check that depends on the input argument can be implemented as a method.

for example

```
public bool CanExecuteCloseDocument (int blah) => Documents.Any(); 
public void ExecuteCloseDocument (int blah) { Documents.Remove(Documents.Last()); }
```

That aside the main issue here is that the view is unaware of the changes to the collection to know to refresh property changes.

Refer to this http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Announcing-PostSharp-42-RC

> #### Dependencies to collections
>
> When you add the `[AggregateAllChanges]` attribute to a field or
>   automatic property, any change to a property of the object assigned to
>   this field/property will be interpreted as a change to the
>   field/property itself. The attribute now works only for collections.

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MyWindowViewModel {

    /// Anything bound to this refreshes just fine as expected
    [AggregateAllChanges] // <-- when the collection changes to cause notification
    public ObservableCollection<SomeType> Documents { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>();

   [Command]
   public ICommand AddDocumentCommand { get; set; }
   public void ExecuteAddDocument () { Documents.Add(new SomeType()); }

   [Command]
   public ICommand CloseDocumentCommand { get; set; }
   public bool CanExecuteCloseDocument => Documents.Any(); 
   public void ExecuteCloseDocument () { Documents.Remove(Documents.Last()); }        
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and solved all issues, you are correct both were required. I'm running postsharp 5 that just released and the command documentation is pretty empty but that did the trick and was clearly explained, thank you

Comment: Referring to this post with a similar question I got this answer from PostSharp support: 
"[AggregateAllChanges] does not work on collections due to internal limitations of NPC aspect, we are aware of this problem. Raising command's CanExecuteChanged event is not currently possible... I don't see in any other way than using reflection (ICommand implementation object has OnCanExecute(object) method) to raise the event. I'm sorry for the inconvenience"

Comment: [AggregateAllChanges] is now implemented in PostSharp 6.10

Answer (score 0):

With PostSharp LINQ expression ([or virtual calls, delegates, external methods](https://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-customization)) wouldn't work well for CanExecute's.

But expression on properties that implement INotifyPropertyChanged work fantastic (even for nested properties). ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged, we don't need LINQ:

`public bool CanExecuteCloseDocument => Documents.Count > 0;`